# Rewriting trees in haskell

Tags: haskell, tree, binary-tree

General case: 
I want to know how to write to trees (ie change a specific node at the bottom level, replacing it with a node with a different value that has the old node as its left child and a new node as the right child)

 
 
Specific application that's making it more difficult: 
I'm trying to put together a game resembling 20 questions that reads the existing tree from a file, asks the user various questions, and if it doesn't know the answer will ask the user for a distinguishing question between the final guess and the correct answer as well as the correct answer, and will add the new entry into the game (replacing the position the guess was in with the new question in a node that points to the guess and the answer)

Comment: Do you have any attempts so far?  What does your tree structure look like?

Comment: Yeah, (I have it working now, just horribly inefficiently)
The replace function I ended up using would go through the whole tree and look for nodes with a given input value, then it would replace those nodes with another tree structure  
The tree looked like this : data Tree a = Empty | Node a (Tree a) (Tree a) deriving (Show,Read,Eq)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Oftentimes there's a tight correspondence between Monad structure and this kind of tree grafting. Here's an example

```
data Tree a = Leaf a | Branch (Tree a) (Tree a) deriving Functor

instance Monad Tree where
  return = Leaf
  Leaf a >>= f = f a
  Branch l r >>= f = Branch (l >>= f) (r >>= f)
```

Where `(>>=)` is doing nothing more than leaf extension (tree grafting) based on some function `f :: a -> Tree a`.

Then we can easily conduct the grafting you're looking for

```
graftRight :: Eq a => a -> a -> Tree a -> Tree a
graftRight a new t = t >>= go where
  go a' | a' == a   = Node a new
        | otherwise = Leaf a'
```

But that's terrifically inefficient since it'll visit every `Leaf` in your tree searching for the specific one you'd like to replace. We can do better if we know more information. If the tree is somehow ordered and sorted then you can use [`fingertree`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/fingertree) or [`splaytree`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/splaytree) to conduct an efficient replacement. If we know the node we'd like to replace by its path alone we can use a Zipper.

```
data TreeDir = L | R
data ZTree a = Root 
             | Step TreeDir (Tree a) (ZTree a)
```

Which lets us step in and out of the root of a Tree

```
stepIn :: Tree a -> (Tree a, ZTree a)
stepIn t = (t, Root)

stepOut :: (Tree a, ZTree a) -> Maybe (Tree a)
stepOut (t, Root) = Just t
stepOut _         = Nothing
```

and once we're inside, walk in whatever direction we like

```
left :: (Tree a, ZTree a) -> Maybe (Tree a, ZTree a)
left (Leaf a, zip) = Nothing
left (Branch l r, zip) = Just (l, Step R r zip)

right :: (Tree a, ZTree a) -> Maybe (Tree a, ZTree a)
right (Leaf a, zip) = Nothing
right (Branch l r, zip) = Just (r, Step L l zip)

up :: (Tree a, ZTree a) -> Maybe (Tree a, ZTree a)
up (tree, Root) = Nothing
up (tree, Step L l zip) = Just (branch l tree, zip)
up (tree, Step R r zip) = Just (branch tree r, zip)
```

And edit leaves

```
graft :: (a -> Tree a) -> (Tree a, ZTree a) -> Maybe (Tree a, ZTree a)
graft f (Leaf a, zip) = Just (f a, zip)
graft _ _             = Nothing
```

Or perhaps all of the leaves below a certain location using our bind from above!

```
graftAll :: (a -> Tree a) -> (Tree a, ZTree a) -> (Tree a, ZTree a)
graftAll f (tree, zip) = (tree >>= f, zip)
```

And then we can walk down to any point in the tree before doing our graft

```
graftBelow :: (a -> Tree a) -> [TreeDir] -> Tree a -> Maybe (Tree a)
graftBelow f steps t = perform (stepIn t) >>= stepOut where
  perform =     foldr (>=>) Just (map stepOf steps)          -- walk all the way down the path
            >=> (Just . graftAll f)                      -- graft here
            >=> foldr (>=>) Just (map (const up) steps)      -- walk back up it
  stepOf L = left
  stepOf R = right
```

---

```
>>> let z = Branch (Branch (Leaf "hello") (Leaf "goodbye"))
                   (Branch (Branch (Leaf "burrito")
                                   (Leaf "falcon"))
                           (Branch (Leaf "taco")
                                   (Leaf "pigeon")))

>>> graftBelow Just [] z == z
True

>>> let dup a = Branch (Leaf a) (Leaf a)
>>> graftBelow dup [L, R] z
Just (Branch (Branch (Leaf "hello") 
                     (Branch (Leaf "goodbye") 
                             (Leaf "goodbye"))) 
             (Branch (Branch (Leaf "burrito") (Leaf "falcon")) 
                     (Branch (Leaf "taco") (Leaf "pigeon"))))

>>> graftBelow dup [L, R, R] z
Nothing
```

Generally there are a lot of ways to achieve this goal.

Comment: Thanks!  This is way more efficient than the way I ended up writing (it would search through every leaf rather than keeping a record of the steps taken)